# Antialiasing text on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I have to create `.png`s for a lot of clients that are printed by an industrial inkjet (ads on back of a children's magazines).

Unfortunately, all browsers seem to switch on antialiasing - no matter what I try. Neither CSS nor `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled=false;` seem to work.

Does anyone have any idea to get text displayed on canvas WITHOUT any grey-scaled pixels trying to make the font sharper?

Answer (score 2):

The canvas will anti-alias everything drawn to it, with the exception of *images* when `imageSmoothingEnabled` is set to `false` (and then only for resampling purposes).

There are various options though -

## SVG

Using SVG would be ideal as it is vectors and can be easily converted to postscript. If the printer supports postscript it will rasterize the vectors into the optimal raster-mask and make sharp edges.

## Large bitmap

You can reduce the effect of anti-aliasing by using a very large bitmap, but from my own experience, and probably yours as well, it won't eliminate the gray points.

There is also the risk of meeting the limitation of canvas element itself which in some browsers is limited to 6k. Depending on the printer's DPI this may or may not be enough.

A combination of a large bitmap and threshold (see below) can perhaps get you around this though.

## The Deep Dive implementation

Another way, but more advanced, to get around this is to load the font manually and draw the paths of it using Bresenham or similar algorithm. An additional aspect is that you would need to use polygon fill-algorithms as well (ie. even-odd or non-zero winding).

All this is doable without too much effort:

- To load fonts and get the path data you can use f.ex. **[opentype.js](http://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js/)**
- Use **[Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)** or **[EFLA](http://www.edepot.com/algorithm.html)** for rendering vectors to lines (if needed)
- Use a polygon fill algorithm **[even-odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-odd_rule)** or **[non-zero winding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule)** to fill the polygons (you may get away with normal canvas fill if you can cover the edges with the Bresenham/EFLA lines).

As you are in print industry Open-Type may not be sufficient as Adobe fonts are more common from the typical repository. You can probably get the path data via other means or find the equivalent in an Open Type version or even a SVG font type.

## Threshold

Another approach is to quantize the gray-levels. You can iterate over the bitmap and use a threshold value to set the pixel either transparent or solid color.

The result may not be so good as you will end up with some sharp transitions around some edges. You may however be able to reduce these artifacts depending on the print-resolution as well as the chosen threshold value.

Comment: @Kaiido sorry, how is using a bitmap font a duplicate? Bitmap fonts (in the traditional sense, ie. small sizes) are very anti-print :)

Comment: @kaiido The topic for this thread seem to be "Antialiasing text on canvas" and my answer is one way to deal with that. Is that not on-topic?

Comment: It would seem to me that one solution would be to simply increase the size of the canvas to as big as possible. This would minimise the size antialiasing pixels. On top of that rendering text several times will sharpen the contrast of the aliasing, or writing a simple threshold clamp... render text to offscreen canvas, apply threshold clamp on pixels `if(alpha < threshold){ alpha = 0;} else { alpha = 255}` and then drawing the offscreen canvas to the working canvas should reduce the problem. Or use SVG rather than canvas.